# Insert and select from other table and contant value

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking to "mark" entries of my SQLite database. This following command will add new entries from the `other_table`:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO landing_table (idx)
SELECT gidx FROM other_table
```

However, I want to update only the entries that don't exist in `landing_table` that do exist in `other_table` to have the value computed set to 1.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO landing_table idx (idx, computed)
SELECT gidx FROM other_table
AND SET computed=1
```

Obviously this isn't correct. I would like to do this in a single insert statement rather than an insert and future `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Your second sentence is confusing; are you saying you want to insert rows that don't exist, but if they do exist, then set `computed` to `1`? (Also what's wrong with 2 statements + a transaction?)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes that's correct. I want to skip rows if they exist, but if they don't I want to insert them _and_ set `computed=1`. I currently do this in two transactions but it's slow as I have to re-search the table to find the ones I've inserted. I was hoping to do this in one statement. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a constant value for `computed`.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO landing_table idx (idx, computed)
SELECT gidx, 1 FROM other_table
```

Comment: Oh! That's legal? I was trying some crazy syntax since I thought (reading the docs) that each item in the select had to be a column. Thanks!